# Open bounded set $E$ so that $m(E)\neq\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}m(O_n)$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $E$ be a compact set and let us define the series:
$$O_n=\{x\in R^d |d(x,E)<1/n\}$$

I proved that:
$$m(E)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}m(O_n)$$

Now I'm trying to find an **open** bounded set $E$ for which this quality does not hold. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $d=1$, $\{r_j\}$ an enumeration of rationals of $[0,1]$ and $E:=\bigcup_{j=1}^{+\infty}(r_j-\delta 2^{-j},r_j+\delta 2^{-j})$. Then $O_n\supset [0,1]$ for each $n$, but $\mu(E)\leqslant \delta$.